# How can I repair engineered hardwood flooring damaged by an office chair?

Tags: engineered-flooring

We have engineered hardwood and the area under our desk is all white and hazy. We bought rubber casters for the chair and a plastic mat to go under it but they still look terrible. I think maybe from dirt particles collecting along the edges so it's like it sanded off the finish of something. Any suggestions on how to fix?

Comment: I'd be tempted to start by giving the area a swipe with mineral spirits. If that makes the problem vanish until it dries, you can probably get away with just putting down a  layer or two of fresh varnish, though there are the usual compatibility questions.

Comment: Are you sure it's engineered hardwood and not laminate?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much of a fix you are willing to accept some engineered hardwood allows for one sanding and refinishing that may be your best option if you want it back to perfect condition if not you can try to match the stain and just go over that area a little bit that will probably not provide what you're looking for the refinishing the entire surface would probably be the best bet if the material you have allows for 1 refinishing

Comment: I have to add one thing to this that white haze you have might be something cause about moisture getting trapped under that piece of plastic maybe you can be buffed out check to make sure that the finish is removed or not just discolored